# Stack two set of numbers in plt bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a graph which stack two numbers based on two different dataframes. But with everything I've tried, the outcome is still lacking the proper display.

```
df1.plot.bar(color = 'r')
df2.plot.bar(color = 'b', bottom = df1)
plt.show()
```

Should I first convert the number to a list for better graph? or should I follow steps to make some other changes?

[image]

Comment: In how far is this problem related to "the titanic dataset"? See [mcve] and create one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to plot the two plots in the same axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3], columns=["red"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([3,2,2], columns=["blue"])

ax = df1.plot.bar(color = 'r')
df2.plot.bar(color = 'b', bottom = df1["red"], ax=ax)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see that your original question was about the titanic dataset. [This one](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/07/titanic-machine-learning-guide-part-1.html), I assume. Then you could simply create the graph with pandas:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
titanic = pd.read_excel("titanic3.xls")
titanic.groupby(["pclass", "sex"])["survived"].mean().unstack().plot(kind = "bar", stacked = True)
plt.show()
```

This creates a multiindex data frame with `pclass` and `sex` and calculates the mean of `survived` for each category. After unstacking it creates the desired stacked bar plot.
[image]